# Promise.all(ref.map(async (file) => ref1.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to switch to Promise from forEach because of asynchronousness.

I've tried:

```js
const ref1 = await firestore.collection("collection").get();
await Promise.all(ref1.map(async (doc) => {

// ...

}));
```

But it throwns : `TypeError: ref1.map is not a function`.
(I'd like to loop through ref1 documents)

Complete code: https://pastebin.com/9sBZ8wY1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref1` is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) that does not have a `map()` function. It has a `docs` property that is an array of `QueryDocumentSnapshot`. Try:

```
const ref1 = await firestore.collection("collection").get();

const data = ref1.docs.map((doc) => {
  return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }
}));
```

Comment: The confusion probably came from the fact that `QuerySnapshot#forEach` exists, yet it's not an array and doesn't have `QuerySnapshot#map`.

Comment: and now `doc` has a doc.ref property as in forEach? Because now I have `Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. At least one field must be updated. at WriteBatch.update` error in `batchArray[batchIndex].update(doc.ref, documentData);`

Comment: @faccio it does have a `ref` property. For that other error, seems like the data is empty or any of the field is undefined or so. Can you please post the relevant code block, screenshot of logs and what the `documentData` contains perhaps in a new question so everyone else can take a look at the new issue?

Comment: Perfect thank you. I'll open new question if I can't came up with a solution

Comment: @Dharmaraj If you'd like to take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74232885/19290739